# I got a type error in python for not using supported tuple and int. What does this mean?

Tags: python

While I run my code it happens successfully and the objective of the game is to click the ball thats bouncing around and exit if not clicked on the ball. Though when clicking th ball or somewhere lse on the display, it gives the following error

> if ((mouseX, mouseY), x,y) <= radius:
> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

While debugging i found out that the problem was coming from this line `if ((mouseX, mouseY), x,y) <= radius:`

What does this error mean and how do i fix it?

this is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import sign
import pygame

def distance(pos1,pos2):
    return sqrt((pos1[0]-pos2[0])**2+(pos1[1]-pos2[1])**2)

dx = 3
dy = 4
x = 100
y = 100
radius = 20
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        mouseX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if ((mouseX, mouseY), x,y) <= radius:
                dx = dx+sign(dx)
                dy = dy+sign(dy)
            else:
                exit()

    display.fill((100, 100, 100))
    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
    pygame.draw.circle (display, (200,200,200), (x,y), radius)
    if (x< radius or x>500- radius):
        dx = -dx
    if (y< radius) or (y>300- radius):
        dy = -dy


    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What would `((mouseX, mouseY), x,y) <= radius` be supposed to mean? If you meant the distance between two points, you have to explicitely write that into your code.

Comment: Substitute numbers for variables and try to tell what `((mouseX, mouseY), x,y) <= radius` should be yourself. Does `((1, 2), 3, 4) <= 5` make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

So one data structure is tuples, think of it as an immutable list. You can make a tuple by using brackets `()`. What you are trying to do is compare a tuple of values to a single integer value.

Also, note that your tuple contains three values, a tuple and two ints. So if you want to access the mouseX for example you'd access it like tuple[0][0].